# What are the ramifications of a copyright holder publicly stating they will not sue an infringer on that right?

Tags: copyright

If someone infringes another's copyright and the owner publicly says it's ok, does he lose any further right to enforce it?

For example, party A has written a book creating a fictional character. Party B uses that character without notifying the copyright holder. Party A is made aware of this during a media interview and says that he is fine with party B's use and has no intention of suing.

How much does a public announcement like that affect the owner's copyright? Can he later change his mind and sue for infringement? If party B continues to use the character in future works, such as a sequel, can party A then sue? Can a third party legally use the character, acting on the assumption that party A has no wish to enforce his copyright?

Comment: Promissory estoppel is a thing to look up, here, but I don't see it applying to an additional party or usage. It does make any suit a bit more challenging than necessary for the copyright holder. Your title was also very misleading, so I've made it reflect your actual question.

Comment: The issues are: statute of frauds and whether there is reliance to support promissory estoppel (a contract argument would ordinarily not prevail for lack of consideration). Resolving those issues and the related ones you suggest are tricky and depend on the exact wording of the statement and context to some extent.